# How to manage change Emailid and Change Password for user logged in using Social Media in Django all-auth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

How can I give the option to change Email-Id and change Password for users logged in through AllAuth [Gmail / Facebook].

Comment: By making a form where they can edit their email and giving them the 'reset password' option? Please be more specific, showing what you're tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I have tried for normal user, where user can change emailid and password. But for all-auth user the email id is there in the db, but the password is unkown by us.

Comment: For your social account users, show them the password set form (not the password change form). Since they don’t have a password.

Comment: Ok, but what if they want to change email id ? How will the logic work?

Comment: As far as I know you can just use the same process as for non social users. The SocialAccount is linked to the User instance so it will still work if they change their email. Note: always make them verify their email before actually setting it to be the primary email. In allauth a user can have multiple emails.

Comment: My process is to let them add a second email and when it’s verified they can change it to primary email. Like LinkedIn.